# How to Create a table that changes size based on a determined value

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

VBA CODE:
 I have a series of tables (one per sheet) that need to increase or decrease in size dynamically, based on number that has been input by a user (on another sheet).

Each row in each of the tables needs to maintain the formatting and formulas from the rows above, whilst being "inserted".

I have used the below to successfully increase the size of the table with the correct formatting, but this only adds rows to the table.. and if someone clicks the macro button multiple times we could end up with far too many rows. Hence why I would like a dynamic table where the rows are determined by a number and it wouldn't matter if someone was click happy.

I have also made another attempt which does increase the size of the table, but it doesn't insert additional rows, so the table overlaps data that is in rows below the determined table. This attempt does not copy the formatting either... but this is all i have so far. Any help would be much appreciated, I've been working on this for a couple of months and can't find a suitable answer (after days of searching).

```
Sub InsertNumberOfRows()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim NBOFROWS As Range
Dim wkb As Workbook


Set NBOFROWS = Worksheets("Rates").Range("K4")


Set wkb = Workbooks("POD Automation10.1")

With wkb

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("POD Cost Plan")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Development Calculator")
Set sh3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calculator Calculations")


sh1.Select
Rows("10:10").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(NBOFROWS.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

sh2.Select
Rows("10:10").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(NBOFROWS.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

sh3.Select
Rows("10:10").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(NBOFROWS.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End With


End Sub



NEXT ATTEMPT:


Sub InsertNumberOfRows()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim Value As Range
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set Value = Worksheets("Rates").Range("K4")

Set wkb = Workbooks("POD Automation10.2")

With wkb

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("POD Cost Plan")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Development Calculator")
Set sh3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calculator Calculations")


sh1.Select

  Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("POD_CostPlan_Tbl")

 Set rng = Range("POD_CostPlan_Tbl[#All]").Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + Value, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)

  tbl.Resize rng


sh2.Select

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TBL_UserEntry")

  Set rng = Range("TBL_UserEntry[#All]").Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + Value, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)

 tbl.Resize rng


sh3.Select

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TBL_Calculations")

  Set rng = Range("TBL_Calculations[#All]").Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + Value, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)

  tbl.Resize rng

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Is this all happening in one workbook? How are the values in the tables changed? I mean there must be formulas in them or are you populating them with another program?

Comment: This is all happening in one workbook. Each of the tables has different data which is obtained and calculated by different paremeters within the work book. e.g. lot length and width is from a drop down box in one table, another table calculates the value of the landscaping for that lot (on an item by item basis) based on the lot size, and another table presents the information in a useable manner.  This is why I need all formulas to transfer to each non-header row in the table, and all tables to increase/decrease depending on the number of lots in the

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use `ListObject` properties to add rows and columns.  For example:

```
 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
     ' Insert column at the end of table:
      .ListColumns.Add
     ' Add row tp the bottom of table:
      .ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:= True
 End With
```

Comment: IF the number decreases (e.g. was input at 30, and changed to 20) all of the tables would be too big and have errors.. the table needs to be able to shrink or grow based on the number of lots..

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would change all those to Tables, so everything (rows and columns) gets updated automatically.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

`Ctrl+T:`  This shortcut converts a range of related information to an Excel Table.  To use this shortcut, just select any cell in a range of related data first.

Comment: Hi ryguy72, they're all tables at the moment.. I'm looking for the length (rows) of the table to change base on an input value. E.g. input value is 30, therefore 30 (non-header) rows are required in the table.